# Apple security tool: how to delete a private key from a keychain?

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm looking for a way, using Apple's security tool, to delete a private key from the keychain. In this specific case, the private key also has a certificate associated with it with which it forms an identity (certificate + private key), so you can click on the "certificates" section of Keychain Access, right-click on the "Imported Private Key" in the drop-down menu and click "Delete":

[image]

As far as I can tell, however, there is no way to do this using the `security` tool (cf. https://ss64.com/osx/security.html); the commands available for deleting are

```
> security help | grep delete
    delete-keychain                      Delete keychains and remove them from the search list.
    delete-generic-password              Delete a generic password item.
    delete-internet-password             Delete an internet password item.
    delete-certificate                   Delete a certificate from a keychain.
    delete-identity                      Delete an identity (certificate + private key) from a keychain.
```

`delete-identity` would also delete the certificate. Is there any way to programmatically achieve the same effect as the Keychain Access command?

(I did notice [Delete Private Key from Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747679/delete-private-key-from-keychain) and [Delete Private key from keychain mac programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824829/delete-private-key-from-keychain-mac-programmatically) which have references to Swift and Objective-C solutions, but I'd prefer to use either Go or an Apple command-line tool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this circuitously by using `security delete-identity` to delete the certificate and private key and then using `security import` to re-import just the certificate.